# How can I deploy a resource file to scaled gears?

Tags: openshift

I have a nodejs app on openshift cloud services. We're storing sensitive info (api keys, passwords, etc.) in a configuration file outside of git (using the node config package, and a default.json). I had set up a deploy action hook to copy this file from $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR to $OPENSHIFT_DEPLOYMENTS_DIR, which worked fine as long as the app didn't scale. However,once the app scales, this file does not exist. Is there any way I can copy a file into an openshift scaled gear?

I realize I could store the info in a database, or use 3rd party storage like S3, but I'd really like to know if there's a way to do this without changing how we are storing the data or adding another dependency.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - I've figured out a workaround. I edited the build configuration script in Jenkins (click on the build name, configure, scroll to bottom) and added the following line:

```
rsync $upstream_ssh:'$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/default.json' $WORKSPACE/config/
```

above the line

```
# Build/update libs and run user pre_build and build
```

This seems to copy the file into the build workspace, which is then propagated to all the build deploys. I haven't been able to test 100% that this happens on auto-scaled gears, but it seems like it does.

If anyone reads this and thinks this is a terrible idea, please let me know.